# forbid arc in created project

Tags: iphone

I created an project with arc.
I used some sample codes to compile, it reported a lot of ARC restrictions error

Is it possible to forbid arc later?

Welcome any comment

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Xcode-Disable ARC at project level:**

```
 - Select your project file. 
 - You should be in the “Build settings” tab.Select the “levels” option (default is “Combined”)
 - There’s a search      field to the right of “Combined”.Enter “Automatic”
 - Second group    should be “Apple LLVM Compiler 3.0 – Language”.
   Second line under    that controls ARC.
 - Click that line, then in the middle column (where    it says “yes”),
   click and choose “no”.
```

**Disable ARC for a single file:**

It is possible to disable ARC for individual files by adding the `-fno-objc-arc` compiler flag for those files.

You add compiler flags in `Targets -> Build Phases -> Compile Sources`. You have to double click on the right column of the row under Compiler Flags. You can also add it to multiple files by holding the cmd button to select the files and then pressing enter to bring up the flag edit box.