# confused by ARC

Tags: iphone, xcode, automatic-ref-counting

The codes below I used on Xcode 3.2 and worked very well

```
@interface MoObject : UIViewController 
{

    NSMutableArray *categoryArray;     
}



@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *categoryArray;

@end;



@implementation MyObject

@synthesize categoryArray;


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
     [super viewDidLoad];


    NSMutableArray *a = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    categoryArray = a;
  [a  release]; //AAA:I can not release this, it does not report compiling error , but after some operation, it will cause exec bad error

}
- (void)dealloc {

    [category release];

    [super dealloc];
}
```

I just move to Xcode 4.3.1 iOS 5.1

the same function causes so many exec bad error.

Even I close the ARC of whole project.

The problem still exist, it looks like I can not release the object array at point AAA

Welcome any comment

Comment: Why are you releasing the categoryArray in dealloc? Is it retained anywhere? That might be the issue.

Comment: @property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *categoryArray;

Answer (score 2):

The point of ARC is that it handles the retain/release code for you. Since your array "a" is declared locally, when that function ends, ARC will insert the code release it for you. Same for dealloc - you don't need it with ARC (and actually can't use it).

But if you don't like or want to learn ARC you don't have to use it. It's an option when you create a new project.

Comment: I try to close arc follow :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9784082/forbid-arc-in-created-project but it look likes arc still works!

Answer (score 2):

You are not using ARC. If you were, code using `-release` would not even compile. Neither would calling `[super dealloc]` in your `-dealloc` method.

What you have is just an ordinary memory management bug.  You are assigning `a` directly to the instance variable `categoryArray`. You are not using the setter which is synthesized for the property and it is the setter which does the proper memory management.  Therefor, `categoryArray` ends up pointing to a deallocated object.  If you were to use either `self.categoryArray = a` or `[self setCategoryArray:a]`, which are equivalent statements, then your bug would go away.

Under ARC, this bug would be mostly hidden. The `categoryArray` instance variable would by default be `__strong`, so the array would be retained at least as long as `categoryArray` pointed to it and you wouldn't get `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` errors.  However, it's still buggy to directly assign to it, bypassing the setter, except within initializer methods.